# Repeatable questions

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm trying to create a daily personnel report. Each manager needs to report who their personnel are, whether they are Present, Sick, On Leave, etc, and where they are. I then plan on having a set of Sheets collate and organize the data, creating a summary for the director. Each day, we'll save off a copy for record.

However, with people constantly coming and going from our organization, I need the managers to be able to add people to their report, without me changing the forms.

Is it possible for me to create a question that is asked over and over again, appending data to the Sheet, until a termination button is clicked? Or can I create a form where the user can add a new row if needed?

Ideally, I'd like the managers to be able to look over their full report while editing it. That will reduce errors and misses.

Comment: you should consider giving up on Form and have it all done in Google Sheets in which you can easily achieve all what you request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to create a question that is asked over and over again, appending data to the Sheet, until a termination button is clicked?

One way to do something similar to this is to use sections to include the a copy of the question that should be asked over an over and a radio button question to ask if the response is done. Set it to go to the next section if the user choose No and to submit the form if the user choose yes.

You should add as many sections as you expect that your users will require, like the maximum number of employees that a manager should report, but bear in mind that the response will not be saved until the form is submitted, so if the Google Form window/tab is closed before the form is submitted the manager should start again.

> Or can I create a form where the user can add a new row if needed?

The only way to do this is by allowing users to edit the form but the changes could affect the previous submitted responses, if someone remove a question the previous saved answers will be lost.

Comment: Yeah. it sounds like the best way to tackle this is just to have a Google Sheet that everybody can fill in. Thank you for the response!